# Sending Header in Get Request

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send a get request reguest in Flutter. But I keep getting HTML codes back.

In Postman, I have to specify `accept: application/json` to be able to get the  JSON. But the tutorial I am following, it wasn't mentioned.

Here is my code below

```
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://libriboo.com/api/landing');
  //  var res = json.decode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
  }
```

I am getting this

```
I/flutter ( 5134):   <head>
I/flutter ( 5134):     <title>Libri</title>
I/flutter ( 5134):     <!-- Required meta tags -->
I/flutter ( 5134):     <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href=".\images\favicon.png">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\assets\css\style.css">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\assets\css\bootstrap.css">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\assets\css\font-awesome.css">
I/flutter ( 5134):     <script src="..\assets\js\script.js"></script>
I/flutter ( 5134): 
I/flutter ( 5134): 
I/flutter ( 5134): 
I/flutter ( 5134):   </head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xtremeCODE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12160025/xtremecode) you can specify `content type` in `header` as following:

```
void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://libriboo.com/api/landing',headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    });
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that during request there is server side error, try to print statusCode  or try like this

```
void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://libriboo.com/api/landing', 
        headers:{ "Content-Type":"application/json"}
      );
  print(response.statusCode);
    //  var res = json.decode(response.body);
    // print(response.body);
}
```